# Using the critical points, I found where the intervals where f(x) is increasing/decreasing on [-4,4], but it was flagged wrong and I'm not sure why.

Tags: calculus, functions

Here's the question as well as my answers. I got some right and some wrong, and I'm confused as to why:

**Identify the intervals where** $f(x) = \frac{1}{4}x^4+\frac{1}{3}x^3-8x^2-16x$ **is increasing and where decreasing on the interval** $[-4, 4]$. **Then, determine the relative extrema of** $f(x)$. **Lastly, determine the absolute extrema of** $f(x)$.

**Increasing (This one was incorrect):** $[-4,-1]$

**Decreasing (Incorrect):** $[-1,4]$

**Local Minimum (Incorrect):** $(-4, -\frac{64}{3})$

**Local Maximum (Correct):** $(-1, \frac{95}{12})$

**Absolute Minimum (Correct):** $(4, -\frac{320}{3})$

**Absolute Maximum (Correct):** $(-1, \frac{95}{12})$

I'm self-studying Calculus 1 for Engineers because of a credits situation with my university. The extrema I thought I understood, but, as I stated in the title, I absolutely made sure I was following the process exactly as I should be, since this topic is very foggy for me. Upon substituting the values from $[-4, 4]$ in $f'(x)$, which is $f'(x) = x³ + x² -16x -16$, I've found the critical points to be $-4, -1,$ and $4$, and I found which intervals were increasing/decreasing.

Some of my answers were still incorrect, though, and I'm not sure why. It won't let me view the correct ones either. I can't re-attempt the question anymore but I'd love to add clarification in my notes for future reference. Any help to clear this up would be greatly appreciated. Thank you! :)

EDIT: I'm wondering if it's because I used brackets instead of parentheses...

Comment: Please see **Edit-Images** section of [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) and then edit your posting accordingly.

Comment: 1. Please don't use images; they are not searchable, and may not display correctly for everyone; use MathJax. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/742). 2. Please make titles informative as to the mathematical content of your question, not about you. They are meant to help people know what the post is about, and to show up when people search for similar questions.

Comment: Do you know interval testing for finding intervals? You said “and when cross referenced to the graph, I found which intervals were increasing/decreasing”. Also, what answers did you type in exactly?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for letting me know! I've edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Was this graded by a computer, or a person? Do you know the specific formatting that they require in the former case?

Comment: @TymaGaidash I've edited my post so hopefully it's more clear, but for interval testing, IIRC, it's finding the point where the derivatives of the numbers between [-4.4] when plugged into f'(x), which I realized I left out and will add now, are equal to 0, which gives us the critical points. Using those critical points can tell us which values are increasing or decreasing. That's how I understand it, anyway, but I could be wrong. :)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin It was graded by a computer. They do use specific formatting, such as entering "4 * x^2" instead of just "4x^2", but usually if I format it incorrectly, a warning sign will pop up telling me that the program is unable to review my answer because of a format error, or something.

Comment: The local minimum may be a matter of convention: some require a local minimum to be an interior point of the domain, and explicitly exclude endpoints. Alternatively, if the endpoint is included as a possibility, then note that the value at $4$ is **also** a local minimum (since it is the smallest value the function takes on the interval $[-1,4]$ of the domain), but you forgot to include it. I would agree with your intervals of increase and decrease, but it is possible that your convention omits the endpoints (I would not omit them, in fact I make a point of including them, but who knows...)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The textbooks I've taught at all specify open intervals for increasing/decreasing,  even though the definition makes perfect sense to include endpoints.  Go figure.

Comment: @Alan: Yeah, I would flag that as incorrect. The Mean Value Theorem tells us that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f'(x)\gt 0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$, then for every $x_1,x_2$ with $a\leq x_1,x_2\leq b$ we have $f(x_1)\lt f(x_2)$, so we *should* include the endpoints. I will note that looking at my copy of Briggs/Cochran/Gillett/Schulz, 3rd Edition, it says "If $f$ is continuous on an interval $I$ and differentiable at all interior points of $I$, if $f'(x)\gt 0$ at all interior points of $I$, then $f$ is increasing on $I$." That includes endpoints when applicable

Comment: Ohh, I see. Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry to bring this back up, but I thought that when an interval is surrounded by brackets, that means they are included in the answer, and the parentheses mean they are excluded.

Comment: @comingundone Yes, that is correct. The bracket includes the endpoint, the parenthesis excludes it. I would answer as you did, with brackets. But some books have the convention that they do not include endpoints in these situations (so you would be expected to use parentheses instaed).